# The method flatMap() in the type Mono<PortCall> is not applicable for the arguments ((<no type> prev)->{})

Tags: java-8, spring-webflux

I'm getting this error: The method flatMap() in the type Mono is not applicable for the arguments (( prev)->{})

```
public Mono<PortCall> updateByFindById(String gsisKey, PortCall portCall) {
    PortCall next = portCallRepository.findById(portCall.getNextPortCall().getNextScheduleEntryKey()).toProcessor().block();
    return portCallRepository.findById(gsisKey)
            .switchIfEmpty(Mono
                    .error(new DataNotFoundException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, PortCallConstants.PORT_CALL_NOT_FOUND)))
            .flatMap(retrivedPortCall -> {
                
                PortCall prev1 = portCallRepository.findById(retrivedPortCall.getPreviousPortCall()
                        .getPreviousScheduleEntryKey()).flatMap(prev->{
                             prev.setNextSiteCode("");
                             prev.getNextPortCall().setNextScheduleEntryKey(next.getGsisKey());
                             prev.getNextPortCall().setTerminalCode(next.getSiteRkstCode());
                             prev.getNextPortCall().setCityCode(next.getCityCode());
                             prev.getNextPortCall().setCityName(next.getCity());
                             prev.getNextPortCall().setTerminalName(next.getSiteName());
                             prev.getNextPortCall().setArrivalVoyage(next.getArrivalVoyageCode());
                             prev.getNextPortCall().setDepartureVoyage(next.getDepartureVoyageCode());
                             portCallRepository.save(prev);
                        });
```

Comment: what does `portCallRepository.save(prev)` return? cause that is what you are trying to stick into `PortCall prev1` which i dont belive is right. You cant return a concrete value from a `flatMap` it needs to be either of type `Mono` or type `Flux`.

Answer (score 1):

The expression `(( prev)->{})` signifies that you are not returning anything with your lambda implementation inside the flatmap call whereas the flatmap contract expects that `? super Optional<U>` should be returned.

As [Toerktumlare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1840146/toerktumlare) suggests, `portCallRepository.save(prev);` should return an Optional, if a concrete value is returned try using `map` instead or if nothing is returned, add a return statement.